# A class can only be a template for a single object not a template for a collection

Tags: vb.net, oop

I have a simple class `List.vb` which is the following:

```
Public Class List

    Public fList As List(Of Integer)
    Public Sub New()
        fList = New List(Of Integer)
        fList.Add(1)
        fList.Add(2)
        fList.Add(3)
        fList.Add(4)
        fList.Add(5)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `Console` application is using this class like the following:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim fObject As List = New List
        Dim cnt As Integer = 0
        For Each x As Integer In fObject.fList
            Console.WriteLine("hello; {0}", fObject.fList.Item(cnt).ToString())
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit")
        Console.Read()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Can I change the class code so that List.vb is a list(of integer) type?
This would mean that in the Console code I could replace `In fObject.fList` with just `In fObject`?
Or am I barking up the wrong tree - should classes be single objects and lists should be collections of classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that dasblinkenlight has provided is excellent, but if all you need is a list that of integers that is pre-populated, you can just inherit from `List(Of Integer)` and then have the class populate itself in the constructor:

```
Public Class List
    Inherits List(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New()
        Add(1)
        Add(2)
        Add(3)
        Add(4)
        Add(5)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When you inherit from `List(Of Integer)`, your class automatically gets all of the functionality implemented by that type, so your class also becomes a list class that works the same way.  Then, you can just use it like this:

```
Dim fObject As New List()
For Each x As Integer In fObject
    Console.WriteLine("hello; {0}", x)
Next
```

Comment: Actually, no.  Good point.  I took it out of my example.  Since the `List(T)` class has a constructor that takes zero arguments, then that base constructor will be called automatically before any code in your own `Sub New`.  The only time you need to explicitly call `MyBase.New` is if you are calling one of the base constructors that takes arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. In order for an object to be compatible with `For Each`, it must have a `GetEnumerator` function:

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator _
  Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return New IntListEnum(fList)
End Function
```

The `IntListEnum` class must, in turn, implement `IEnumerator`, like this:

```
Public Class IntListEnum Implements IEnumerator

Private listInt As List(Of Integer)

Dim position As Integer = -1

Public Sub New(ByVal fList As List(Of Integer))
    listInt = fList
End Sub 

Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
    position = position + 1
    Return (position < listInt.Count)
End Function 

Public Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
    position = -1
End Sub 

Public ReadOnly Property Current() As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
    Get 
        Try 
            Return listInt(position)
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
            Throw New InvalidOperationException()
        End Try 
    End Get 
End Property
```

End Class

Now you can make `fList` private, and iterate your `List` as follows:

```
For Each x As Integer In fObject
```

You can see a complete example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: ... to add the function `GetEnumerator` to my Class List I assume the class will need to `Implements IEnumerable`?

Comment: @whytheq My understanding is that although implementing `IEnumerable` is very common, from the point of view of the language it is optional: the "for each" loop figures out to call `GetEnumerator` even without you implementing the interface.

Comment: if I do not add `Implements IEnumerable` for the calling Class then the function `GetEnumerator` (which is part of this class) shows a problem on the line `Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` with a message `interface 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is not implemented by this class` p.s well done hitting 100k !

Comment: @whytheq I guess it's a difference between VB and C# then?